# Include Module Method in Nested Model Class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

In several places in my codebase, I have a hard-coded integer that I have to pull into a method so it can be changed in one place. I have created a module in `lib/due_date.rb` and added a method:

```
module DueDate
  def due_date(days=10)
    days
  end
end
```

I've included it in some model class and it works fine (these classes are not nested). The issue I'm having is including it in nested model classes. For instance, when the model class looks like this:

```
module A
  module B
    class C
      include DueDate
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'due_date' for #<Class:......>
```

In `class C`, I'm first trying to assign it to a constant that's used in other places in the class:

```
THRESHOLD = due_date
```

The second place I'm trying to use it is in a `scope` with a where clause:

```
scope :range -> {
  .where("due_date <= NOW() + INTERNAL '#{due_date} days'")
}
```

How can I include my `DueDate` module in the nested classes so I can use the `due_date` method in these two ways?

**UPDATE:**
including the module in the class works fine, so it's how I'm trying to use the method that isn't working.

Comment: This should work. Can you show how you are calling the method?

Comment: You're not really showing the full context of where you're using it. This constant assignment and scope, are they inside the instance context of `class C`?

Comment: You're still not showing the full context. "Inside class C" doesn't answer whether it's in class or instance scope. Remember, each class can be interacted with at the class or instance level. Siim's answer addresses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the method to be available as an instance method, then everything you're doing is correct.

However, from your examples it looks like you're trying to use it as a class method instead. To achieve that, you need to `extend` the module rather than `include` it.

```rb
module A
  module B
    class C
      extend DueDate

      THRESHOLD = due_date
    end
  end
end

A::B::C::THRESHOLD #=> 10
A::B::C.due_date #=> 10
```